# WHERE clause running differently depending on parameter value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a large query:

```
DECLARE @userParam VARCHAR(100)
    ,@startDateParam DATETIME
    ,@endDateParam DATETIME
    ,@orgTeamPK VARCHAR(100)
    ,@search VARCHAR(100)
    ,@productId VARCHAR(100)
    ,@themeParam VARCHAR(100)

SET @userParam = 'David Tunnell (tunnelld)'
SET @startDateParam = '2014-01-27'
SET @endDateParam = '2014-02-02'
SET @orgTeamPK = '%'
SET @search = '%'
SET @productId = '%'
SET @themeParam = '%'

SELECT '3' AS RowType
        ,DTH.EnteredBy AS Person
        ,COALESCE(PDT.[Name], APP.AppName) AS Project
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN (
                        STY.KanBanProductId IS NOT NULL
                        AND STY.SprintId IS NULL
                        )
                    THEN 'KanBan'
                WHEN (
                        STY.KanBanProductId IS NULL
                        AND STY.SprintId IS NOT NULL
                        )
                    THEN 'Sprint'
                ELSE SCY.Catagory
                END
            ) AS ProjectType
        ,COALESCE(STY.[Number], NSS.IncidentNumber) AS StoryNumber
        ,COALESCE(STY.Title, NSS.[Description]) AS StoryTitle
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), STY.Effort) AS Effort
        ,COALESCE(TSK.[Name], '') AS Task
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), TSK.OriginalEstimateHours) AS OriginalEstimateHours
        ,SCY.Catagory AS Category
        ,NSS.IncidentNumber AS IncidentNumber
        ,APP.AppName AS ApplicationName
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 2
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS MondayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 3
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TuesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 4
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS WednesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 5
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS ThursdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 6
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS FridayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 7
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SaturdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 1
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SundayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(DTH.[Hours]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TotalHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DTH.Hours > 0
                        THEN DTH.[UserDifference]
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS DifferentUsers
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DTH.Hours > 0
                        THEN DTH.DoubleBookedFlag
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS DoubleBookedFlag
        ,DTH.PointPerson AS PointPerson
    FROM DailyTaskHours DTH
    LEFT JOIN Task TSK ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
    LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
    LEFT JOIN NonScrumStory NSS ON DTH.NonScrumStoryId = NSS.PK_NonScrumStory
    LEFT JOIN SupportCatagory SCY ON NSS.CatagoryId = SCY.PK_SupportCatagory
    LEFT JOIN [Application] APP ON NSS.ApplicationId = APP.PK_Application
    LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
    LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
    LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON DTH.EnteredBy = USR.DisplayName
    LEFT JOIN [StoryProductTheme] SPM ON STY.PK_Story = SPM.StoryId
    LEFT JOIN [ProductTheme] PTM ON SPM.ProductThemeId = PTM.PK_ProductTheme
    WHERE DTH.EnteredBy LIKE @userParam
        AND ActivityDate >= @startDateParam
        AND ActivityDate <= @endDateParam
        AND 1 = CASE ISNUMERIC(@productId)
            WHEN 0
                THEN CASE 
                        WHEN DTH.TaskId IS NULL
                            OR PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId
                            THEN 1
                        END
            WHEN 1
                THEN CASE 
                        WHEN DTH.TaskId IS NOT NULL
                            AND PDT.PK_Product = @productId
                            THEN 1
                        END
            END
        AND (
            (
                @orgTeamPK = '%'
                AND (
                    USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK
                    OR USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] IS NULL
                    )
                )
            OR (
                @orgTeamPK <> '%'
                AND (USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK)
                )
            AND (
                (
                    STY.Number LIKE @search
                    OR STY.Number IS NULL
                    )
                OR (
                    STY.Title LIKE @search
                    OR STY.Title IS NULL
                    )
                OR (
                    TSK.NAME LIKE @search
                    OR TSK.NAME IS NULL
                    )
                )
            )
    GROUP BY DTH.EnteredBy
        ,PDT.[Name]
        ,SPT.[Name]
        ,SPT.[Description]
        ,STY.[Number]
        ,STY.Title
        ,TSK.[Name]
        ,SCY.Catagory
        ,NSS.IncidentNumber
        ,APP.AppName
        ,STY.KanBanProductId
        ,STY.SprintId
        ,NSS.[Description]
        ,TSK.OriginalEstimateHours
        ,STY.Effort
        ,DTH.PointPerson
    HAVING SUM(DTH.[Hours]) > 0
```

Whan I am trying to do is add the ability to filter in a specific way. Here is the code I am adding to the WHERE clause:

```
    AND (
        ISNUMERIC(@themeParam) = 0
        AND PTM.ThemeId LIKE @themeParam
        )
    OR (
        ISNUMERIC(@themeParam) = 1
        AND @themeParam = 6
        AND STY.KanBanProductId IS NULL
        AND STY.SprintId IS NOT NULL
        )
    OR (
        ISNUMERIC(@themeParam) = 1
        AND @themeParam <> 6
        AND PTM.ThemeId = @themeParam
        )
```

This is my goal with the code:

If `@themeParam = '%'`, I want the first portion to run because `ISNUMERIC(@themeParam)` should evaluate to zero.

If `@themeParam = 6`, I want the second portion to run and return all values `STY.KanBanProductId IS NULL AND STY.SprintId IS NOT NULL`.

If `@themeParam <> 6`, I want the first to run, returning only where `PTM.ThemeId = @themeParam`.

I have two problems. Fist of all I am getting the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type
>   int.

I would think that if `ISNUMERIC(@themeParam)` does not evaluate to 1, the rest of the code would not run and it wouldn't try to compare '%' to 6.

My second problem is that when I do input a number for `@themeParam` the query runs but seems to ignore all of the other portions of my where clause and I don't understand why.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: While using control code in SQL is often ill advised I think in this case it makes sense.  You are going to get much better performance if you use an if statement and write out the 3 different select statements.

Comment: It could also make sense to write 3 different stored procedures and call the correct one from the client code.

Comment: And the @Hogan suggestion will let your code much more readeable.

Comment: Could you please show an example of what you mean with the if statements?

Comment: Do you need a set of parentheses surrounding your entire set of OR conditions? Right now, you have AND () OR () OR (). Do you mean AND (() OR () OR ())?

Answer (score 1):

Do not add criteria for the outer joined tables to the WHERE clause but to the ON clause or consider NULLS. Here is why: Once there is no matching record in an outer joined table like PTM a pseudo record is being created with all values set to NULL. When asking for PTM.ThemeId LIKE @themeParam OR ... you may mistakenly eliminate those records again.